# How to retrieve specifics a firebase database entry?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to retrieve data fields from the data that I have stored in a firebase realtime database, and I'm stuck.

This is what my database looks like:
[image: firebase realtime database]

This is a method that I've called in my AuthStateListener object and is defined as follows:

```
private void alterTextView(final String id) {
    if(id!=null) {
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (ds.exists()) {
                        UserInformation userInformation = ds.child(id).getValue(UserInformation.class);
                        String name = userInformation.getName();
                        mWelcomeUserMessage.setText(name);
                        //logging name
                        Log.d("My activity", "name of user with userID - " + id + " is : " + userInformation.getName());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The call to this function is as such:

```
 mAuthStatelistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            //if user is logged in, the sign_in and sign_up buttons should not be displayed
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                userId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                Log.d("Main Activity", "Current userId : " + userId);
                alterTextView(userId);
                mLogInButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mSignUpButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //getUserName(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                mLogOutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mLogInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSignUpButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mWelcomeUserMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mLogOutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    };
```

For some reason, I keep getting a null pointer exception in the first excerpt of code in the line where I store the name from the userInformation object -

```
String name = userInformation.getName();
```

I just can't understand why this is happening.

My main goal is to print out the name of the logged in user once he/she has logged in.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

**Update 1** This is what my UserInformation class looks like:

```
public class UserInformation {

private String name;
private String student_number;
private String faculty;
private boolean isAdmin;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getStudent_number() {
    return student_number;
}

public String getFaculty() {
    return faculty;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isAdmin() {
    return isAdmin;
}

public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
    isAdmin = admin;
}

public void setStudent_number(String student_number) {
    this.student_number = student_number;
}

public void setFaculty(String faculty) {
    this.faculty = faculty;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The loop in your `onDataChange()` method isn't needed:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (ds.exists()) {
        UserInformation userInformation = ds.child(id).getValue(UserInformation.class);
        String name = userInformation.getName();
        mWelcomeUserMessage.setText(name);
        //logging name
        Log.d("My activity", "name of user with userID - " + id + " is : " + userInformation.getName());
    }
}
```

A loop is only needed when you use a query with a value listener, since a query can have multiple results. But in your case you directly access the correct child node, so a loop is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a non exist child, that's the reason you are getting null value. Your listener already listens to "id child", replace the following line:

```
 UserInformation userInformation = ds.child(id).getValue(UserInformation.class);
```

By:

```
 UserInformation userInformation = ds.getValue(UserInformation.class);
```

Then, back to your **UserInformation.class**, add the following changes:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties // Add this tag
public class UserInformation {

    private String name;
    private String student_number;
    private String faculty;
    private boolean isAdmin;

    //Define this constructor
    public UserInformation() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class)
    }
    // The rest of your class ...

}
```

Comment: I made the change, but now, instead of a null pointer exception, when I try to invoke setText() on my textView, i don't get anything.
Furthermore, this shows up in my log:

06-05 16:10:09.022 4812-4812/com.example.android.fireapp D/My activity: name of user with userID - ITDpaqPfEFY7AdE20vjHbeU84eV2 is : null.


**For some reason, the field is still null**

Comment: Could you post your UserInformation.java? @YashChowdhary

Comment: So I gave it a default value of "" in the default constructor, and that's what's being displayed. It seems that the getValue() method doesn't alter the 'name' attribute

Comment: Did you modify UserInformation class as I told you? The default constructor must be empty @YashChowdhary

Comment: Yes, I added the default constructor and gave all the attributes default values (to all strings, i assigned "" and I assigned 'false' to the boolean) @AlexTa

Comment: oh, it must be empty? Got it